a Latin inequality
This is a Futoshiki puzzle. You  must put a single digit (1 through 7) in each empty square so that

each row and each column has exactly one of each digit, and
the inequality signs between adjacent squares are true.

The following puzzle is taken directly from Simon Tatham's collection (where he calls the puzzle type "Unequal"). It's one that I found especially interesting, which is why I'm sharing it with you.

This puzzle is also solvable on Mr. Tatham's site.

I assume brute force computer programs are not allowed ?

@FirstNameLastName "allowed"? You can do what you like. But what would be the point of such a solution? What would you or anyone else gain from your solving it that way? Heck, if you want a computer solution, just follow my link to Simon Tatham's site and click "Solve game": it'll do it for you.

OP could have used the no-computers tag if they really didn't want a programming-based solution, so it's allowed.

Solution (removed the guessing phase; guessing wasn't necessary):

 

